# Scrape posts on Imgur using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, imgur

I want to scrape posts from Imgur.

Let's say we have this link(permalink): https://imgur.com/gallery/ZXjNfqu/comment/1717354251

I want to load this url via `HttpURLConnection` and read some data from content(HTML).

I have this code:

```
try{

    //create connection
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(url)).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //get response
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

        //read html
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        try(var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                body.append(line);
            }

        }

        //print html
        System.out.println(body.toString());

    }else{

        //read error content
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        try(var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()))){

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                body.append(line);
            }

        }

        String bodyStr = body.toString().trim();
        throw new Exception("Bad HTTP Request: " + responseCode +
                            " - " + connection.getResponseMessage() +
                            (bodyStr.isEmpty() ? "" : " - " + bodyStr));

    }

}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Via `HttpURLConnection` I get only a part of the real page(what I see in browser). From `HTML` is missing at least image url and comments.

How I can get all content via `HttpURLConnection`?

P.S.: Is not necessary to use `HttpURLConnection`

**Edit 1:** I think it's because of javascript. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps use [HTTPClient](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html_) class? Regarding `HttpURLConnection`, have you read [Dodge the traps hiding in the URLConnection class](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075162/dodge-the-traps-hiding-in-the-urlconnection-class.html?nsdr=true) ?